# SessionFactory error in "Hibernate Configuration" - Eclipse Juno

Tags: hibernate, jboss, eclipse-plugin, sessionfactory

I am using eclipse Juno for development.

I have added 'JBoss Tools (Juno)' from Eclipse Marketplace to my eclipse for hibernate application development.

When I tried to add Hibernate Configuration to auto generate POJO and hibernate configuration files, I am getting errors.

Below is my hibernate configuration I am using.

[image]

I am getting errors below while accessing session factory and database using hibernate configurations.

1. Error while accessing session factory. It also includes error logs.

[image]

[image]

2. below is the error message I am getting while accessing database.

An internal error occurred during: "Fetching children of Database".
org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

These errors unable me from auto generating POJO files.

Kindly guild or provide me a solution.